# Decryption of Windows HDD

Tags: windows-7, decryption

Is it possible to decrypt a windows HDD (encrypted using BitLocker and Windows 7) using Ubuntu? I could not found any information on this? The problem is I know just the administrator password of my Windows PC. Anytime I switched the PC on the HDD was decrypted when I logged on to the Windows. If I take out my HDD and connect it to the Ubuntu PC could I decrypt my HDD and use it?

Comment: I found this on the forum:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/90673/how-to-decrypt-a-windows-folder-in-ubuntu
But the post is about 2 years ago. I do not know if since then a solution was  found?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use (Windows) BitLocker-encrypted drive on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/617950/use-windows-bitlocker-encrypted-drive-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts)

Answer (score 0):

Bitlocker is a proprietary, closed-source drive encryption system only supported by Windows. Better is you remove Bitlocker encryption if you want to access your Windows partitions from Linux.

There is some tools though, one of them is dislocker.

http://www.hsc.fr/ressources/outils/dislocker/